# How to get the name of model passed into the function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have set a ng-model to a input test in HTML

```
<input ng-model="nnvalue.temp" ng-change="updateValue(nnvalue.temp)"/>
```

on the function updateValue(val), i 've written like the following

```
$scope.updateValue=function(val) {                
            alert("op is" +val);
        }
```

Output:
      If i type "s" i am getting the alert message "op is s"

What i need is, i need to get the name of model to be printed in alert (i.e) "op is **nnvalue.temp**"

Can anyone tell me how to do this

Thanks

Comment: I assume you want this to be done automatically? I mean you could also simply pass in the value as a string: `<input ng-model="nnvalue.temp" ng-change="updateValue("nnvalue.temp")"/>`

Comment: can you make a plunker?, because i have something similar to and everything work fine for me

Comment: @Anzeo i need to create a key value pair using the ng-model name and its value

Comment: I understand what you're after, I'm asking whether it's feasible to pass in the name of the model as well or if you'd like this to be done automatically?

Comment: @Anzeo I like this to be done automatically

Comment: Why would you want this to be done automatically ? What do you expect to gain ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem what i need to do is, i will put a condition with in the function to check from which model the value is changing, based on that, i will update the respective key

Comment: @surendher: Wy don't you just pass in the key, check it and then access and update the value based on that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html to this

```
<input ng-model="nnvalue.temp" ng-change="updateValue('nnvalue.temp')"/>
```

The ' ' around the variable name makes it a string, without this it gives the value of that variable